# How to add horizontal scrolling to a table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a table in which I have fixed headers and vertical scrolling on the `tbody`. However, the columns in this table can grow significantly and I'd like to add horizontal scrolling. At the moment when there are more than 3 columns, the table doesn't look right.

JS Fiddle with three columns (how it should look): https://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/DTcHh/42626/

JS Fiddle with four columns (this should look like the three column fiddle): https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/67311/

I believe the problematic class is `header-fixed`. It has the following:

```
.header-fixed > tbody > tr:after,
.header-fixed > thead > tr:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}
```

Which is stopping the rows from being overflown.

Comment: did you want each row to overflow or in what circumstance did you want it to overflow

Comment: I would like the body of the table (ones with checkboxes) to overflow horizontally whenever the rows do not fit in the width. Example of this is when I have four columns

Comment: This does not address your core desire, but as you are using Bootstrap you *could* simply wrap your table in `<div class="table-responsive">...</div>` which causes the ENTIRE table to gain a horizontal scrollbar when needed.

Comment: @RobertC I tried that but it doesn't have an effect

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the link below:

[Check the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/67312/)

I have removed float and added flexbox instead and added #Row1 styles to achieve overflow. I hope this helps.

```css
.header-fixed > thead > tr > th {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 20%;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
}

#Row1 {
  overflow-x: scroll;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: Hi - I am not sure whether you posted the wrong url but on the js fiddle link you shared, I'm not seeing the columns lining up with the checkboxes

Comment: see this link: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/67317/ I am bit unsure what you're trying to achieve.